# How to call dynamic menu on each page in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, menu

I am new in Spring. I want to call dynamic menu on each page in Java Spring.
I am just creating a simple cms portal and I am managing all menu in database, now I want to call this menus in each page i.e in header. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow, and I'd further regard it as too broad for anywhere. Good questions will contain obvious evidence of prior research, which means sitting down with a search engine and **spending several hours** trying different phrases, getting links, reading material and trying code snippets. It may be that you have fallen into the trap of asking a question prior to doing any research at all, and unfortunately volunteers here do not have the resources to do that research for you.

Comment: Thus, I would recommend that you spend time reading the manual (really in detail) or searching the web (including Stack Overflow). Try something, anything - this is the journey that helps you become more self-sufficient as a programmer. Good luck!